# Refresh partial form on submit | Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Rails 7.0.4.3 | Ruby 3.2.2**

Let's say I have a page `some_page.html.erb`.
It has a partially rendered form for user authorization that leads to `user_controller.rb` on submit.
How do I display data in this form, based on controller response, without page refresh?

```html
# some_page.html.erb

<div class="modal-container">
  <%= render partial: 'sign_in' %>
</div>
```

```html
# app/views/_sign_in.html.erb 

<div class="sign-in-modal">
  <%= form_with url: '/find_user', method: 'post', id: 'find-user', remote: true do |form| %>
    <div class="form-input-field">
      <%= form.label :login, 'Login' %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :login %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-input-field">
      <%= form.label :password, 'Password' %><br>
      <%= form.password_field  :password %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= form.submit 'Sign in' %>
    </div>

    <div class="error-msg">
      ...
      PLACE FOR THE ERROR
      ...
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

```rb
# users_controller.rb

def find_user
  user = User.find_by login: params[:login], password: params[:password]

  if user.nil?
    # make form display error
  else
    # some successful authorization logic, i.e. redirect_to
  end
end
```

##### I tried to do this:

```rb
if user.nil?
  respond_to do |format|
    flash[:notice] = 'NO USERS FOUND!'
    format.html { render partial: 'pages/sign_in' }
  end
end
```

```html
<div class="error-msg"
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
</div>
```

But it would just do nothing and show `Form responses must redirect to another location` error in browser console. And only if I reload the page, it will show the error from `flash` in the form.

If I add status 500, as it was suggested in some other SO thread:
`format.html { render partial: 'pages/sign_in', status: :500 }`
It would just erase the whole page and render the form in its place.
What should I do?

Comment: There's a missing `>` on your flash notice.  It's probably just a typo while submitting on SO, but FYI just-in-case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work if you send `422`, `:unprocessable_entity`.

```
format.html { render partial: 'pages/sign_in', status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

This is so that Turbo Drive, which intercepts and handles the responses by default in Rails 7, [knows how to handle the response](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#redirecting-after-a-form-submission).

I'm not sure why you're rendering just a partial here, but presumably you have a reason.  It's fairly normal to render a full-page though, even if it's just a small wrapper around the form partial.

---

*Tip in case you're learning Rails*: A good way to learn or review the standard patterns like this is by using a scaffold in rails and reading through its code.  You can generate a scaffold via `rails g scaffold Foo name password`. You'll see it does something fairly similar in the FooController's `#create` and `#update` methods.

Comment: `> I'm not sure why you're rendering just a partial here`
I have a pop-up modal for account login that user can call on any page of my site, and it's closed by default, and I wanted it to render errors right there.
Well. seems like it's not fully possible without custom ajax request with js. But you still helped me a little, thanks.

Comment: Did the 422, unprocessable_entity not work?